# How to replace text over multiple lines using preg_replace

Tags: php

Hi have the following content within an html page that stretches multiple lines

```
<div class="c-fc c-bc" id="content">
                <span class="content-heading c-hc">Heading 1 </span><br />
                The Home Page must provide a introduction to the services provided.<br />
                <br />
                <span class="c-sc">Sub Heading</span><br />
                The Home Page must provide a introduction to the services provided.<br />
                <br />
                <span class="c-sc">Sub Heading</span><br /> 
                The Home Page must provide a introduction to the services provided.<br />
            </div>
```

I need to replace everthing between `<div class="c-fc c-bc" id="content">` and `</div>` with custom text

I use the following code to accomplish this but it does not want to work if it's multiple lines, but works if evertinh is in one line

```
$body = file_get_contents('../../templates/'.$val['url']);

$body = preg_replace('/<div class=\"c\-fc c\-bc\" id=\"content\">(.*)<\/div>/','<div class="c-fc c-bc" id="content">abc</div>',$body);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: For multiline/dotall regex you'll also want to be very careful with that greedy `.*`, which will cause the very last `</div>` end-tag on the entire page to be matched. Maybe you want the first `</div>` end-tag in which case you'd need a non-greedy `.*?`. If you want the *matching* `</div>` end-tag, there is no way regex can work that out. Did we mention, **don't** use regex to parse HTML?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If this weren't HTML, I'd tell you to use the [DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier to change the meaning of `.` from 'match everything except new line' to 'match everything':

```
preg_replace('/(.*)<\/div>/s','abc',$body);
```

But this is HTML, so use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: works great!. I was trying by replacing new lines with trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $input)) . It was working with PHP test run online but was not working in my code.

Answer (score 22):

it is the "s" flag, it enables . to capture newlines

Comment: Documentation for PHP: s (PCRE_DOTALL)
If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` combined with the DOTALL flag `s` for matching everyting because `[\s\S]` means exactly the same: match everything; \s matches all space-characters (including newline) and \S machtes everything that is not a space-character (i.e. everything else). in some cases/implementations of regular expressions, this works better than enabling DOTALL

caution: `.*` with the flag for DOTALL as well as `[\s\S]` are both "hungry" and won't stop reading the string. if you want them to stop at a certain position, (e.g. the first *</div>*), use the non-greedy operator `?` behind your quantifier, e.g. `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

How would it be possible to replace text between nested tags, like that:

```
$sExample2 = "Test [DIV]again[/DIV]
d[COLOR=rgb(184, 49, 47)][SIZE=26px][B][U]o[/U][/B][/SIZE][/COLOR]ssed

This is not [DIV]true[/DIV] !

Yes it is [DIV]true [DIV]but[/DIV] just [/DIV] in that case!.

Why not [DIV]now

?[/DIV] Right here.

Because it is [DIV]down
[DIV]to the [/DIV][/DIV] botton.

I know but i want to [DIV]fly
[DIV]far[/DIV]
[/DIV] away.

";
```

I want to replace each DIV tuples with * Help *, so that the result looks like

```
Test ** Test **
d[COLOR=rgb(184, 49, 47)][SIZE=26px][B][U]o[/U][/B][/SIZE][/COLOR]ssed

This is not ** Test ** !

Yes it is ** Test ** in that case!.

Why not ** Test **
 Right here.

Because it is ** Test ** 
botton.

I know but i want to ** Test **
 away.
```

I tried different replacements, but never received such a result.

```
print_r(preg_replace(
            '#\[' . preg_quote('DIV', '#') . '](.*?)\[\/' . preg_quote('DIV', '#') . '\]#si',
            '*** Test ***',
            $sExample2
        ));
```

This one was nearly the best but not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use regex to strip out chunks of html data, but you need to wrap the html with custom html tags which get ignored by browsers. For example:

```
<?php
$html='
<div>This will be shown</div>
<custom650 rel="nofollow">
  <p class="subformedit">
    <a href="#" class="mylink">Link</a>
    <div class="morestuff">
      ... more html in here ...
    </div>
  </p>
</custom650>
<div>This will also be shown</div>
';
```

To strip the tags with the rel="nofollow" attributes, you can use the following regex:

```
$newhtml = preg_replace('/<([^\s]+)[^>]*rel="nofollow"[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/si', '', $html);
```

From experience, start the custom tags on a new line. Undoubtedly a hack, but might help someone.