# regex - multiple line quote

Tags: php, regex

I'm having an issue with regex:

```
$var = preg_replace("/\[doxer_quote\]([^]]+)\[\/doxer_quote\]/", '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $var);
```

I'm trying to make it show the content inside a `blockquote` tag but I can't figure it out. It needs to go over multiple lines as well. Can someone help me out.

Comment: What is your input string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex works fine with strings containing no "tags" inside `[doxer_quote]`, e.g.:

```
[doxer_quote]my 
  multiline 
  text[/doxer_quote]
```

but it fails with nested tags, even with single-line contents, e.g.:

```
[doxer_quote]my [strong]formatted[/strong] text[/doxer_quote]
```

The reason is that you are matching everything up to the `]` character by this repeated character class: `[^]]+`, so it breaks when the first nested tag is met.

Solution: replace `[^]]+` with a `.+`, **and** include the `s`-modified to your regex, i.e.:

```
$var = preg_replace("/\[doxer_quote\](.+)\[\/doxer_quote\]/s", '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $var);
```

The `s`-modifier (called [PCRE_DOTALL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)) makes the dot match any character, including newline.

---

### Processing nested elements

If your markup language is allowed to contain nested `[doxer_quote]` elements, then it is not [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Regex is there for processing regular languages only.

There is *no elegant way* to match nested elements by the regex. Think of the following situation:

```
[doxer_quote]
  [doxer_quote]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  [/doxer_quote]
[/doxer_quote]

consetetur sadipscing elitr

[doxer_quote]
  sed diam nonumy
[/doxer_quote]
```

You cannot process it with a *single* regex invocation.
But it can be done in a loop as follows:

```
while(($var2 = preg_replace("/\[doxer_quote\]((?:(?!\[doxer_quote\]).)+?)\[\/doxer_quote\]/s", '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $var)) !== $var)
  $var = $var2;
```

Step-by-step explanation:

- `.` matches any character
- `(?!\[doxer_quote\]).` matches any character, which is not the start of the sequence "[doxer_quote]". `(?!)` is called [negative lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).
- `(?:(?!\[doxer_quote\]).)` is the above grouped into a [non-capturing subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).
- `(?:(?!\[doxer_quote\]).)+` matches the subpattern [repeated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) one or more times.
- `(?:(?!\[doxer_quote\]).)+?` - the `?` after the `+` repetition quantifier makes the quantifier [lazy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) (also called *non-greedy*).
- `((?:(?!\[doxer_quote\]).)+?)` - the parentheses define a [capturing subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). It is referred to by `$1` in the replacement expression.
- In the loop, the *innermost* tags are replaced in every step. If the string didn't change after an iteration, the loop breaks.

### Final notes

- If you are sure that your markup is always properly formatted (e.g. every opening tag is closed) and the tags of your markup language do not contain attributes or the like, consider [replacing](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) start tags and end tags directly, without matching the content:

  ```
   $var = str_replace(
            array('[doxer_quote]', '[/doxer_quote]'), 
            array('<blockquote>', '</blockquote>'), 
            $var
          );
  ```

  You can process multiple tags (not only `[doxer_quote]`) in one step this way.
- Consider parsing your markup language.

Comment: I have one problem now. Say I want to do `[doxer_quote]Hello[doxer_quote]hey[/doxer_quote][/doxer_quote]` How would I do that? I always get it displaying the one inside as text.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been such a help!!

Comment: it was a pleasure to help :)

Answer (score -1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2101427/2277620. Use the multiline- modifier, but if you leave the "+" greedy, you will get the text from first block beginning to last block end.

Comment: The `/m` flag only affects `^` start and line end `$` markers, which aren't used here. You are likely referring to the `/s` DOTALL modifier, which however only affects the `.` dot meta character.