# preg_replace remove linebreak between custom tags

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, preg-replace

So if a user enters [tag]hello[/tag] then it works great. However, if a user enters:

[tag]Hello

How are you[/tag]

with a line break in the form, the content between the [tag] [/tag] dose not get effected by the action. (.*?) is something missing here?

```
function tag($string) {
    $rules = array(
        '#\[tag](.*?)\[\/tag\]#i' => '<font style="color: #7c7c7c; font-style: italic;"> $1 <br><hr style="border-style: dotted; border-top: none; border-color: #9f9f9f;"></font>'
    );

    foreach ($rules as $link => $player)
        $string = preg_replace($link, $player, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: try the `s` flag, as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101409/how-to-replace-text-over-multiple-lines-using-preg-replace)

Comment: I can not get it to work, i tried a bunch of different ways, closest i got was with (.*?)s?\ but without the result I wanted.

Comment: the answer below was what i meant.. (#(regex-here)#is) ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this that worked for me:

```
<?php
//
function tag($string) {
  $rules = array(
    '#\[tag](.*?)\[\/tag\]#is' => '<font style="color: #7c7c7c; font-style: italic;"> $1 <br><hr style="border-style: dotted; border-top: none; border-color: #9f9f9f;"></font>'
  );

  foreach ($rules as $link => $player)
  {
    $string = preg_replace($link, $player, $string);
  }

  return $string;
}

//
// test 1:
//
$string = '[tag]Hello How are you[/tag]';
//
echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">"
  . tag($string)
  . "</textarea>";

//
// test 2:
//
$string = '[tag]Hello

How are you[/tag]
';
//
echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">"
  . tag($string)
  . "</textarea>";
?>
```

The modifiers 'is' are:

```
i: ignore case.
s: treat the text in single line mode.
```

Comment: ah, i feel like an idiot now, thanks man! works like it should now.